# PermissionError when deleting a directory

Tags: python

This is the code:

```
os.mkdir("""d:/toto""")
os.remove("""d:/toto""")
```

The script creates a directory which I can see in Explorer. But the script can't delete it. I get the following error:

> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Accès refusé: 'd:/toto'

How to make a directory and delete it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `os.rmdir` to delete directories, not `os.remove` which removes files.

Answer (score 2):

- If you are using **Windows**, make sure your path is correctly use `\\` instead of `\`
- If you are using ***nix**, you should use `/` instead of `\`.

In Windows, to create a directory, you can use

```
>>> os.mkdir("d:\\todo")
```

To delete a directory, you can try

```
>>> os.rmdir("d:\\todo")
```

Just a reminder, if you are using ***nix**, make sure you have the write permission to create/delete folders, or you can run the python script as `root`.

Comment: `"d:\\todo"` won't work because the first backslash is just an escape for the second. Either use `"d:\\\\todo"` or the raw string `r"d:\\todo"`.

Comment: the OP is using / which works fine for nix and windows

Answer (score 1):

You might have to give permissions while creating the directory. Try a

```
os.mkdir("d:/toto", 0o777)
```

This will give read/write permission to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running windows, right click the python file and run as administrator.
If you're in linux try "sudo (The name of the file)".